# How to fix net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR socket.io

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, sockets, netty-socketio

I have created socket application in sprintboot (backend) and angularjs (frontend) after deploying both over EC2 (AWS) I am getting `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error in my frontend.
In backend I am getting - `Blocked wrong request! url: /bad-request, ip: null`

[image]

I am using netty-socket.io, and TimeMe.js library

Thanks in advance.